# Numba: how to parse arbitrary logic string into sequence of jitclassed instances in a loop

Tags: python, numba

**Tl Dr**. If I were to explain the problem in short:

1. I have signals:

```
np.random.seed(42)
x = np.random.randn(1000)
y = np.random.randn(1000)
z = np.random.randn(1000)
```

2. and human readable string tuple logic like :

```
entry_sig_ = ((x,y,'crossup',False),)
exit_sig_ = ((x,z,'crossup',False), 'or_',(x,y,'crossdown',False))
```

where:

- `'entry_sig_'` means the output will be `1` when the time series unfolds from left to right and `'entry_sig_'` is hit. `(x,y,'crossup',False)` means: `x` crossed `y` up at a particular time `i`, and `False` means signal doesn't have "memory". Otherwise number of hits accumulates.
- `'exit_sig_'` means the output will again become '0' when the `'exit_sig_'` is hit.

3. The output is generated through:

```
@njit
def run(x, entry_sig, exit_sig):
    '''
    x: np.array
    entry_sig, exit_sig: homogeneous tuples of tuple signals
    Returns: sequence of 0 and 1 satisfying entry and exit sigs
    ''' 
    L = x.shape[0]
    out = np.empty(L)
    out[0] = 0.0
    out[-1] = 0.0
    i = 1
    trade = True
    while i < L-1:
        out[i] = 0.0
        if reduce_sig(entry_sig,i) and i<L-1:
            out[i] = 1.0
            trade = True
            while trade and i<L-2:
                i += 1
                out[i] = 1.0
                if reduce_sig(exit_sig,i):
                    trade = False
        i+= 1
    return out
```

`reduce_sig(sig,i)` is a function (see definition below) that parses the tuple and returns resulting output for a given point in time.

**Question:**

As of now, an object of `SingleSig` class is instantiated in the for loop from scratch for any given point in time; thus, not having "memory", which totally cancels the merits of having a class, a bare function will do. Does there exist a workaround (a different class template, a different approach, etc) so that:

1. combined tuple signal can be queried for its value at a particular point in time `i`.
2. "memory" can be reset; i.e. e.g. `MultiSig(sig_tuple).memory_field` can be set to `0` at a constituent signals levels.

Comment: I believe simplicity of an availabilile solution hinges on how simplified the problem is. How many different price time-series are to be compared at max?

Comment: @NicMoetsch Each signal operates on 2 time series, which could be coded as strings, hinting to columns in a pandas df or a numpy structured array, or simply 2 numpy arrays as in the presented simplified example. If we talk about all the signals combined (say 5 signals *on average*), 5*2=10, but note as well, most of signals will share time series they operate on.

Comment: Ok, could you elaborate how 'memory' is supposed to work? If `self.acc` were True and thus self.out was > 1, you'd be using binary operators on non binary values in the for loop in `reduce_sig`. Also, isn't the 'combined tuple signal' retrievable from the output array of 0s and 1s? When the output series changes from 0 to 1 from point i to i+1, the combined entry signal at point i will have been 1 else 0.

Comment: @NicMoetsch Please see update. Concerning using binary operators on non-binary values... 0 will evaluate to False in logic comparison; 1,2,3... will evaluate to True

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't use the proper language; `|` and `&` are bitwise operators in python not logical operators. `1 & 2` evaluates to 0 not to 1, even if both values themselves are `True`. Additionally, do I understand correctly from your edit that you're not looking for a solution to 'combined tuple signal can be queried for its value at a particular point in time i.' anymore?

Comment: @NicMoetsch 1. We can change `0` and `1` to `False` and `True`. 2. The whole purpose of the exercise is to query MultiSig (''combined tuple signal") at a particular point in time `i`, sequentially, step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code adds a memory to the signals which can be wiped using `MultiSig.reset()` to reset the count of all signals to 0. The memory can be queried using `MultiSig.query_memory(key)` to return the number of hits for that signal at that time.

For the memory function to work, I had to add unique keys to the signals to identify them.

```
from numba import njit, int64, float64, types
from numba.types import Array, string, boolean
from numba import jitclass
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
x = np.random.randn(1000000)
y = np.random.randn(1000000)
z = np.random.randn(1000000)

# Example of "human-readable" signals
entry_sig_ = ((x,y,'crossup',False),)
exit_sig_ = ((x,z,'crossup',False), 'or_',(x,y,'crossdown',False))

# Turn signals into homogeneous tuple
#entry_sig_
entry_sig = (((x,y,'crossup',False),'NOP','1'),)
#exit_sig_
exit_sig = (((x,z,'crossup',False),'or_','2'),((x,y,'crossdown',False),'NOP','3'))

@njit
def cross(x, y, i):
    '''
    x,y: np.array
    i: int - point in time
    Returns: 1 or 0 when condition is met
    '''
    if (x[i - 1] - y[i - 1])*(x[i] - y[i]) < 0:
        out = 1
    else:
        out = 0
    return out


kv_ty = (types.string,types.int64)

spec = [
    ('memory', types.DictType(*kv_ty)),
]

@njit
def single_signal(x, y, how, acc, i):
    '''
    i: int - point in time
    Returns either signal or accumulator
    '''
    if cross(x, y, i):
        if x[i] < y[i] and how == 'crossdown':
            out = 1
        elif x[i] > y[i] and how == "crossup":
            out = 1
        else:
            out = 0
    else:
        out = 0
    return out
    
@jitclass(spec)
class MultiSig:
    def __init__(self,entry,exit):
        '''
        initialize memory at single signal level
        '''
        memory_dict = {}
        for i in entry:
            memory_dict[str(i[2])] = 0
        
        for i in exit:
            memory_dict[str(i[2])] = 0
        
        self.memory = memory_dict
        
    def reduce_sig(self, sig, i):
        '''
        Parses multisignal
        sig: homogeneous tuple of tuples ("human-readable" signal definition)
        i: int - point in time
        Returns: resulting value of multisignal
        '''
        L = len(sig)
        out = single_signal(*sig[0][0],i)
        logic = sig[0][1]
        if out:
            self.update_memory(sig[0][2])
        for cnt in range(1, L):
            s = single_signal(*sig[cnt][0],i)
            if s:
                self.update_memory(sig[cnt][2])
            out = out | s if logic == 'or_' else out & s
            logic = sig[cnt][1]
        return out
    
    def update_memory(self, key):
        '''
        update memory
        '''
        self.memory[str(key)] += 1
    
    def reset(self):
        '''
        reset memory
        '''
        dicti = {}
        for i in self.memory:
            dicti[i] = 0
        self.memory = dicti
        
    def query_memory(self, key):
        '''
        return number of hits on signal
        '''
        return self.memory[str(key)]

@njit
def run(x, entry_sig, exit_sig):
    '''
    x: np.array
    entry_sig, exit_sig: homogeneous tuples of tuples
    Returns: sequence of 0 and 1 satisfying entry and exit sigs
    '''
    L = x.shape[0]
    out = np.empty(L)
    out[0] = 0.0
    out[-1] = 0.0
    i = 1
    multi = MultiSig(entry_sig,exit_sig)
    while i < L-1:
        out[i] = 0.0
        if multi.reduce_sig(entry_sig,i) and i<L-1:
            out[i] = 1.0
            trade = True
            while trade and i<L-2:
                i += 1
                out[i] = 1.0
                if multi.reduce_sig(exit_sig,i):
                    trade = False
        i+= 1
    return out

run(x, entry_sig, exit_sig)
```

To reiterate what I said in the comments, `|` and `&` are bitwise operators, not logical operators. `1 & 2` outputs 0/False which is not what I believe you want this to evaluate to so I made sure the `out` and `s` can only be 0/1 in order for this to produce the expected output.

You are aware that the because of:

```
out = out | s if logic == 'or_' else out & s
```

the order of the time-series inside `entry_sig` and `exit_sig` matters?

Let (output, logic) be tuples where output is 0 or 1 according to how `crossup` and `crossdown` would evalute the passed information of the tuple and logic is `or_` or `and_`.

```
tuples = ((0,'or_'),(1,'or_'),(0,'and_'))

out = tuples[0][0]
logic = tuples[0][1]
for i in range(1,len(tuples)):
    s = tuples[i][0]
    out = out | s if logic == 'or_' else out & s
    out = s
    logic = tuples[i][1]

print(out)
0
```

changing the order of the tuple yields the other signal:

```
tuples = ((0,'or_'),(0,'and_'),(1,'or_'))

out = tuples[0][0]
logic = tuples[0][1]
for i in range(1,len(tuples)):
    s = tuples[i][0]
    out = out | s if logic == 'or_' else out & s
    out = s
    logic = tuples[i][1]

print(out)
1
```

The performance hinges on how many times the count needs to be updated. Using n=1,000,000 for all three time series, your code had a mean run-time of 0.6s on my machine, my code had 0.63s.

I then changed the crossing logic up a bit to save the number of if/else so that the nested if/else is only triggered if the time-series crossed which can be checked by one comparison only. This further halved the difference in run-time so above code now sits at 2.5% longer run-time your original code.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov I jitted the code, runs in about 1/4 the time now. I'm assuming thats still nowhere close to how fast you need it to run. If `NOP` is always only in the last tuple and all others are `or_`, the `logic` that is applied will always be `or_` as the only `NOP` is unpacked right before the loop terminates. Thus you could drop the if/else which cuts additional 1/4th of runtime. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov Updated the code, run-time is only slightly longer than your original code. Also changed the bit where I talk about tuple order, I'm still not sure if that is adressed properly.

Comment: Thanks for your time again! I have several concerns. (1) In your suggested solution `acc` param doesn't affect what is returned by the signal: instant or accumulated value. (2) You feed entry and exit signals several times: once when you instantiate object, and then when you reduce multisig. Do you see a way (1) to get rid of numbering signals and (2) to not mix entry and exit into one MultiSig instance, thus only having `__init__(self, exit/entry)`, `reduce_sig(self,i)`, and `reset_memory(self)` methods? Then in run we'll have `ms1=MultiSig(entry)` and `ms2=MultiSig(exit)`

Comment: @sergeybushmanov (1)a adding acc is easily solvable, so is (2). (1)b, not numbering signals I'm not so sure of. When using the dictionary apporach we need unique identifiers for each signal. Since variable have no `__name__` attribute, we can't simply combine series1, series2 and crossup/crossdown into unique identifiers. We can outsource the numbering - or the creation of any other unique identifier - to a parsing function you mention in your second comment, so it doesn't have to be done by hand.

Comment: I'm done given some insights I've gained from your approach. Thanks for your time and I appreciate your desire to help!